# Doctrine big query performances

Tags: sql, performance, doctrine, query-builder

Hello Stackoverflow :)

I'm struggling a lot with a big doctrine query, there is 17000 contacts in the database and near 1 millions rows for statistics and orders.

As you can see there is a lot of calculated values, i really need theses values to performs filtering.

At first i tried to do that query with DQL but it's just as bad in term of performances, the query takes more than 15 or 30 seconds..

Is anyone can give me some advices, i'm sure i'm not the only one who needs to do that kind of queries!

Thanks in advance :)

This is the query

```
 $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('contact');

    $qb->select("contact.id");
    $qb->addSelect("contact.source");
    $qb->addSelect("contact.updatedAt");
    $qb->addSelect("contact.createdAt");

    // orders
    $qb->addSelect("COUNT(distinct shop_order.id) AS totalOrders");
    $qb->addSelect("SUM(distinct shop_order.price) AS totalSpentOrders");
    $qb->addSelect("AVG(distinct shop_order.price) AS averageCart");
    $qb->addSelect("MAX(shop_order.createdAt) AS lastOrderDatedAt");
    $qb->addSelect("MIN(shop_order.createdAt) AS firstOrderDatedAt");
    $qb->addSelect("last_shop_order.price AS totalSpentLastOrder");

    // orders statuses
    $qb->addSelect("COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN shop_order.status = " . Order::STATUS_WAITING . " THEN shop_order.id ELSE :empty END)) AS totalOrdersWaitingOrError");
    $qb->addSelect("COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN shop_order.status = " . Order::STATUS_PAID . " THEN shop_order.id ELSE :empty END)) AS totalOrdersPaid");
    $qb->addSelect("COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN shop_order.status = " . Order::STATUS_DELIVERED . " THEN shop_order.id ELSE :empty END)) AS totalOrdersDelivered");
    $qb->addSelect("COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN shop_order.status = " . Order::STATUS_PAYMENT_ERROR . " THEN shop_order.id ELSE :empty END)) AS totalOrdersPaymentError");
    $qb->addSelect("COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN shop_order.status = " . Order::STATUS_SHIPPED . " THEN shop_order.id ELSE :empty END)) AS totalOrdersShipped");
    $qb->addSelect("COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN shop_order.status = " . Order::STATUS_ABORTED . " THEN shop_order.id ELSE :empty END)) AS totalOrdersAborted");

    $qb->leftJoin("contact.orders", "shop_order", Join::WITH, "shop_order.isValid = 1 AND shop_order.contact = contact");
    $qb->leftJoin("contact.orders", "last_shop_order", Join::WITH, "last_shop_order = FIRST(SELECT lso FROM App:Order lso WHERE lso.isValid = 1 AND lso.contact = contact ORDER BY lso.createdAt DESC)");

    // order cart
    $qb->leftJoin("shop_order.cart", "cart");
    $qb->leftJoin("cart.productCarts", "product_carts");
    $qb->leftJoin("product_carts.product", "product");

    // abandonned carts
    $qb->addSelect("COUNT(distinct abandonned_cart.id) AS totalAbandonnedCarts");
    $qb->addSelect("SUM(distinct abandonned_product.price) AS totalAmountAbandonnedCarts");

    $qb->leftJoin("contact.carts", "abandonned_cart");
    $qb->leftJoin("abandonned_cart.shopOrder", "abandonned_shop_order");
    $qb->leftJoin("abandonned_cart.productCarts", "abandonned_product_cart");
    $qb->leftJoin("abandonned_product_cart.product", "abandonned_product");
    $qb->andWhere("abandonned_shop_order.id IS NULL");

    $qb->addSelect("SUM(distinct last_abandonned_cart.amount) AS totalAmountLastAbandonnedCart");

    $qb->leftJoin("contact.carts", "last_abandonned_cart", Join::WITH, "last_abandonned_cart = FIRST(SELECT lac FROM App:Cart lac LEFT JOIN lac.shopOrder lacso WHERE lacso IS NULL AND lac.contact = contact ORDER BY lac.createdAt DESC)");
    $qb->leftJoin("last_abandonned_cart.productCarts", "last_abandonned_product_cart");
    $qb->leftJoin("last_abandonned_product_cart.product", "last_abandonned_product");

    // behavior
    $qb->addSelect("COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN contact_stat.type = " . ContactStat::TYPE_EMAIL_SENT . " THEN contact_stat.id ELSE :empty END)) AS totalEmailSent");
    $qb->addSelect("COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN contact_stat.type = " . ContactStat::TYPE_EMAIL_CLICKED . " THEN contact_stat.id ELSE :empty END)) AS totalEmailClicked");
    $qb->addSelect("COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN contact_stat.type = " . ContactStat::TYPE_EMAIL_OPENED . " THEN contact_stat.id ELSE :empty END)) AS totalEmailOpened");
    $qb->addSelect("(COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN contact_stat.type = " . ContactStat::TYPE_EMAIL_CLICKED . " THEN contact_stat.id ELSE :empty END)) / COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN contact_stat.type = " . ContactStat::TYPE_EMAIL_SENT . " THEN contact_stat.id ELSE :empty END))) * 100 AS emailClickedRate");
    $qb->addSelect("(COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN contact_stat.type = " . ContactStat::TYPE_EMAIL_OPENED . " THEN contact_stat.id ELSE :empty END)) / COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN contact_stat.type = " . ContactStat::TYPE_EMAIL_SENT . " THEN contact_stat.id ELSE :empty END))) * 100  AS emailOpenedRate");
    $qb->leftJoin("contact.contactStats", "contact_stat");

    // other contact informations
    $qb->leftJoin("contact.address", "address");
    $qb->leftJoin("contact.contactOperations", "contact_operation");
    $qb->leftJoin("contact_operation.operation", "operation");
    $qb->leftJoin("contact.accountTypes", "account_type");
    $qb->leftJoin("contact.medicalInformation", "medical_information");

    $qb->setParameter("empty", null);

    $qb->orderBy("contact.updatedAt", "DESC");
    $qb->groupBy("contact.id");
```

I tried to removed some of the joins and the calculated values this is the SQL query :

```
SELECT c0_.id AS id_0, c0_.email AS email_1, c0_.first_name AS first_name_2, c0_.last_name AS last_name_3, c0_.type AS type_4, c0_.updated_at AS updated_at_5, c0_.source AS source_6, c0_.created_at AS created_at_7, a1_.postcode AS postcode_8, a1_.country AS country_9, m2_.skin_type AS skin_type_10, c0_.is_optin_sms AS is_optin_sms_11 FROM contact c0_ LEFT JOIN address a1_ ON c0_.address_id = a1_.id LEFT JOIN medical_information m2_ ON c0_.id = m2_.contact_id LEFT JOIN contact_operation c3_ ON c0_.id = c3_.contact_id LEFT JOIN operation o4_ ON c3_.operation_id = o4_.id LEFT JOIN account_type_contact a6_ ON c0_.id = a6_.contact_id LEFT JOIN account_type a5_ ON a5_.id = a6_.account_type_id LEFT JOIN contact_stat c7_ ON c0_.id = c7_.contact_id LEFT JOIN shop_order s8_ ON c0_.id = s8_.contact_id AND (s8_.is_valid = 1 AND s8_.contact_id = c0_.id) LEFT JOIN shop_order s9_ ON c0_.id = s9_.contact_id AND (s9_.id = (SELECT s10_.id FROM shop_order s10_ WHERE s10_.is_valid = 1 AND s10_.contact_id = c0_.id ORDER BY s10_.created_at DESC LIMIT 1)) LEFT JOIN cart c11_ ON s8_.cart_id = c11_.id LEFT JOIN product_cart p12_ ON c11_.id = p12_.cart_id LEFT JOIN product p13_ ON p12_.product_id = p13_.id LEFT JOIN cart c14_ ON c0_.id = c14_.contact_id LEFT JOIN shop_order s15_ ON c14_.id = s15_.cart_id AND (s15_.id IS NULL AND s15_.contact_id = c0_.id) GROUP BY c0_.id ORDER BY c0_.updated_at DESC;
```

The query take more than 8 seconds..

There is the Explain of the query

[image]

---

Answer (score 0):

Is million rows a lot?  That is dependent on the infrastructure but on modern hardware that should not be a big deal.

What concerns me is that your query has sum ( distinct .... ).  That may be because **without this you were not getting correct results**; a classic mistake when writing queries.  i.e. not choosing correct function because it is needed vs without it not getting correct results.  Doing sum like this seems questionable.

So first execute your query without group by and analyze the results.  Chances are that you may have an undesired cartisian product going on in the data ... which may have led you down the path of putting distincts.  That needs to be fixed first.  If at the end total data set of a million needs to be grouped; based on hardware it should not be a big deal.

Comment: If i not group by contact i have only one single row, the desired result is the 17000 contact with the calculated values for each row

Comment: the million rows are just used to get set calculated values, like the sum of the orders, or the total amount they paid

Comment: So without group by you get correct results?  How long does that query take?  (For such analysis I often do a count(*) so that dont get skewed results because of time it takes for results to show).
Then if you removed all distincts from sum, your result is still correct?

Comment: no without the distinct the calculated values are incorrect, the query take more than 30 seconds with all the joins.. the same if i remove all the select sum ou count

Comment: i added more information with a simpler query without the select sum, etc.. the query took still 8 seconds